# Error with appending custom object to NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I have created a custom object. I have saved the custom object to nsuserdefaults using NSCoder. I added an NSArray to the object and  I am trying to append another custom object to this array. I keep getting this error when trying to do so: "Value of type NSArray has no member append". How can I prevent this error and be able to save my custom object to nsuserdefaults with this array of custom objects.

here is the custom class:

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
var name: String!
var age: Int!
var image: UIImage!
var arr: NSArray!
required convenience init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
    self.name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
    self.age = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("age") as! Int
    self.image = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("image") as! UIImage
    self.image = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("image") as! UIImage    }
convenience init(name: String, age: Int, img: UIImage, array: NSArray) {
    self.init()
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.image = img
    self.arr = array

}
func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        if let name = name { coder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name") }
        if let age = age { coder.encodeObject(age, forKey: "age") }
        if let img = image {coder.encodeObject(image, forKey: "image") }
        if let arr = arr {coder.encodeObject(arr, forKey: "array") }
    }
}
```

here is the saving and appending code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
var newPerson = Person()
var oldPerson = Person(name: "John", age: 100, img: newPerson.image, array: [1, 2, 3, 4])
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func Save(sender: AnyObject) {


    newPerson.name = textField.text
    newPerson.age = 10
    newPerson.image = UIImage(named: "afghan_flag.jpg")
    newPerson.arr.append(oldPerson)
    let personData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newPerson)
    NSUserDefaults().setObject(personData, forKey: "personData")

}


@IBAction func Load(sender: AnyObject) {


    if let loadedData = NSUserDefaults().dataForKey("personData") {

        if let loadedPerson = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(loadedData) as? Person {
            print(loadedPerson.name)

        }
    }strong text


   }
}
```

Comment: NSArray cant be modified (.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have an array of Person if you define it like this

```
var arrayPerson : [Person] = []
```

then you can use arrrayPerson.append(newPerson)